Wordpress - check if get_post(id) is called by page with same ID - infinite cycle
I have a function that can load any page content to another page simply like this:
add_shortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
function fc_load_content($params) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => -1), $params));

    return apply_filters('the_content', get_post($id)->post_content);
}

In any page I can add block with [load_content id="123"] and it will load content of page id 123 to another page. Thats ok. But when I do [load_content id="123"] in page with ID 123 it will cause infinite loop till execution timeout. It's user problem - wrong ID. But how to break this infinite loading loop in function fc_load_content? I wasn't able to get ID of "calling" page so I can't compare it to param ID. Thank you.

Don't worry about getting the id of the calling page.
Just check that the current page is not the page with the id the shortcode is loading. The function is_page() can take an id parameter and returns true or false if that's the current page. Negate it on a conditional gate wrapping your return statement...
    add_shortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
    function fc_load_content($params) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => -1), $params));
        if ( !is_page($id) ) {
          return apply_filters('the_content', get_post($id)->post_content);
        }
    }



The original answer neglects consideration of whether the function in the original question is called in or out of the Wordpress loop depending on where OP's shortcode is entered in the content. The suggested solution therefore produces unpredictable results, and a method which will always reliably get the page id regardless of loop conditions is now suggested:
Try extracting the page from the URL instead.
If using "Plain" permalinks...
add_shortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
function fc_load_content($params) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => -1), $params));
    // Use page id in url query string to check not matching shortcode target
    if ( $_GET['p'] != $id && !is_admin() )
    { 
        return apply_filters('the_content', get_post($id)->post_content);
    }
}

If using "Numeric" permalinks...
add_shortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
function fc_load_content($params) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => -1), $params));
    // Get url path
    $url_path = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
    // Break path into array, excluding empty values before/after starting/ending slashes
    $url_parts = array_filter( explode( '/', $url_path ) );
    // Use last part of url path (page id) to check not matching shortcode target
    if ( $url_parts[count($url_parts - 1)] != $id && !is_admin() )
    { 
        return apply_filters('the_content', get_post($id)->post_content);
    }
}

If using "Post name" permalinks...
add_shortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
function fc_load_content($params) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => -1), $params));
    // Get url path without starting/ending slashes
    $url_path = implode( '/', array_filter( explode( '/', parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH ) ) ) );
    // Get page object which has current url path
    $page = get_page_by_path( $url_path );
    // Use id of page which has current url path to check not matching shortcode target
    if ( $page && $page->ID != $id && !is_admin() )
    { 
        return apply_filters('the_content', get_post($id)->post_content);
    }
}


Function "is_page($id)" always returns false.

I've edited my answer to explain why the initial suggestion is invalid and suggest another approach using URLs to identify the page more consistently. There are a few examples to follow depending on which permalink settings your site uses.

Thank you @Altered-Slate. Third option works on front end! Only problem is with "Preview" in administration wp-admin. There it's different structure and it returns "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

Ah, so you'll need to add a check for whether the function is running in wp-admin as well. Change the line if ( $page && $page->ID != $id ) line to if ( $page && $page->ID != $id && !is_admin() )

is_admin() can't help with ID compare. But I can do check if in preview via $_GET['preview'] and then get 'page_id' param for ID compare. Otherwise (if not in preview) use your solution. Thank you.

I misunderstood what needed to be done when in preview, but glad we got there together.

add_shortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
function fc_load_content($params) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => -1), $params));
    remove_sortcode( 'load_content' );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post($id)->post_content);
    add_sortcode( 'load_content', 'fc_load_content' );
    return $content;
}


Does not work. It stops loading the rest of the page after first "load_content" function on the page. This function can be in multiple block on same page.
